# View all edited questions / answers by me on StackOverflow

Tags: support

Is there a way by which I can see all the questions / answers which I have edited on StackOverflow?

Comment: Sure. In your profile page, under `activity`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1047998/naveen?tab=activity&sort=revisions

Comment: @Oded: Thanks Found it under `activity > revisions`. Would be glad to accept this as answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look in your profile page, under the `activity` tab, looking at the `revisions`:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1047998/naveen?tab=activity&sort=revisions